# Pcap file parsing

Tags: packet-analysis, wireshark

I have a .pcap file that I would like to look at. But when I open it in notepad++ i get strings of discernible information, but a whole lot more of black boxes with 'NUL' written in them.

I know I can use wireshark to open the .pcap file, but i'm trying to see the hexcode for the .pcap file.

Is there anyway to see the .pcap header information in Hex? Also what format is the .pcap file in? Is it a binarycode?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you simply after the hexcode equivalents to captured data?  That already exists in Wireshark with the View\Packet Bytes option.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

> what format is the .pcap file in? Is it a binarycode?

[Yes](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html).

> Is there anyway to see the .pcap header information in Hex?

A [hex file editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor).

Answer (score 2):

wireshark and tcpdump should work. Several other tools as well. But if you have to ask, it probably not the right tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is your best bet. It's also free. Download it, open the pcap, click on a packet, and the very bottom window will show the entire packet in hex and ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

When U use a mac (Mac OS X), you could use: [cocoaPacketAnalyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/)